# Useful notion of ambiguous growing context-sensitive language

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fl.formal-languages, grammars, ambiguity

As far as I understand there is no useful notion of ambiguous context-sensitive language.

For example for any inherently ambiguous context-free language there is a context-sensitive grammar generating it such that every string has a unique derivation tree https://mathoverflow.net/a/172786

What if we restrict to growing context-sensitive languages? Is there a useful definition of ambiguity then?